# suds send None attribute

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

I am trying to call a service that requires Null(None) attributes but suds removes them. I need to send..

```
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:QueryIntersection>
     <ns0:intersectingRoad>
        <ns2:RoadName xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ns2:RoadType xsi:nil="true"/>
     </ns0:intersectingRoad>
     <ns0:subjectRoad>
        <ns2:RoadName>BURKE</ns2:RoadName>
        <ns2:RoadType>ROAD</ns2:RoadType>
     </ns0:subjectRoad>
  </ns0:QueryIntersection>
```

but suds removes the IntersectingRoad object and only sends

```
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:QueryIntersection>
     <ns0:subjectRoad>
        <ns2:RoadName>BURKE</ns2:RoadName>
        <ns2:RoadType>ROAD</ns2:RoadType>
     </ns0:subjectRoad>
  </ns0:QueryIntersection>
```

If I set one of the values in IntersectingRoad object it will send it and work correctly but None is also a valid request.
This is an extract of the code I am using...

```
Int1 = client.factory.create('ns2:IntersectingRoad')
Int1.RoadName = None
Int1.RoadType = None

Int2 = client.factory.create('ns2:SubjectRoad')
Int2.RoadName = "BURKE"
Int2.RoadType = "ROAD"

try:
    Ints = client.service.QueryIntersection(Int1,Int2, )
except Exception as e:
    print e.message
```

Any help please!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suds has special null() function for passing optional parameters, because None is treated as absence of value.

I think your case would look like this:

```
from suds import null

Int1 = client.factory.create('ns2:IntersectingRoad')
Int1.RoadName = null()
Int1.RoadType = null()
```